# jQuery 1.3.2 append() fails in IE7 and IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

The code is simple. Works in every browser but IE.

```
J.get('/upload/uploadresponse/' + uploaded_lessonfile_id , function ( data ){
   J('#upload-files').prepend( data );
});
```

alert() on data shows the required data.
Html is `<div id="upload-files"></div>` - no magic there.

Would prefer not to upgrade to jQuery 1.4. 
Would prefer to wipe internet explorer from the earth.

Comment: Have you tried filling the div with anything? Even an `&nbsp;`?

Comment: Is `data` HTML or something else?

Comment: Thanks, yes. Had &nbsp; in there. Tried just html() as well, to overwrite nested elements. Cheked the DOM as well to not have any errors, since it's html strict.

Comment: Can you post a sample of what data contains

Comment: data is a string. Containing HTML, and a `<script type="text/javascript"></script>` tag

Comment: maybe there is something relating to http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ via $.ajaxSetup() , although "dataType ... "html": Returns HTML as plain text; included script tags are evaluated when inserted in the DOM.". I've since removed the javascript and it still fails to render the html on the page. It's not cached, since the URL is different every time.   

BTW - "J" is jQuery in noConflict() mode.

Comment: jQuery cannot apply any `<script>` tags when using `append()` with a string per default.

Comment: Yeah, loading `<script>` elements into the document is in many ways unreliable cross browser. Just don't do it... there's really no reason to anyway. Keeping your script in static files, or returning executable code to be executed on its own with `eval` if you really really need to, are both much more reliable and less roundabout ways of doing it.

Comment: Thanks. The `<script >` was removed yesterday. Still fails. jQuery _does_ apply them "included script tags are evaluated when inserted in the DOM". see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the response body had invalid HTML - an extra `</div>`. It is inserting into a document that is supposed to be HTML strict.

Answer (score 1):

Have you  tried

> J('#upload-files').html( data );

make sure your string is either

> var data = ' with " quotes inside ';
>   or var data = " using escape \" ";

Comment: Thanks.Yes tried html() - see comment above.

Data is the standard Jquery object/string returned from the Ajax call (in this case jQuery.get() ).

Comment: have now verified that html() also fails, not only for that specific DOM element, but parts of the page. @c0mrade. You might be on the right track. but we've spent 10 hours now.

Comment: yes, my solution above solved it. Will mark solved tomorrow. Invalid HTML strict was the issue. Don't know if that's a jQuery bug or a IE bug, or not really a bug at all, but a feature - and jQuery should just throw an error.